# HTML5 Canvas - Cinema Seating Plan, trying to get chosen seats to become green and red seats to be unavailable

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to create a seating plan for a cinema website i am trying to develop in HTML5 Canvas. 
What i have so far you can see below.

What i am trying to do is have a mouseover function so that when it touches a grey square, the seat turns green and when you mouseover a red seat, a message appears stating that seat is unavailable.

I would be grateful if anybody could help me to solve this issue as i am pulling out my hair over it!

Thanks a Mill,

Lauren :)

[image]

*Partial code:*

[image]

[Code 2][3]

Comment: You need to post code or a fiddle to people can recreate this. Not a picture.

Comment: **You can:** (1) listen for `mousemove` events, (2) clear the canvas and redraw all the seats, (3) get the mouse position, (4) loop through all your seat-rectangles, (5) test if the mouse is inside a seat: `(mouseX>seatX && mouseX<seatX+seatWidth && mouseY>seatY && mouseY<seatY+seatHeight)`. If the mouse is inside a seat, redraw it green or use `fillText` to draw an "unavailable" text.

Answer (score 1):

That must've been a lot of work, individually drawing each seat! Capturing mouse movement will be tough with so many hard-coded locations to deal with, but you'll have an easier time interacting with the seats if you draw them in a loop, like so:

```
var row, seat;
for (row = 0; row < maxRows; row += 1) {
    for(seat = 0; seat < seatsPerRow; seat += 1) {

        if (mouseIsOnSeat(row, seat)) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        } else if (seatIsReserved(row, seat)) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
        }

        // Draw the seat position here
        // (you can account for the aisle by first checking
        // the seat number and adding necessary padding)
        ctx.fillRect(...);

    }
}
```

to implement `mouseIsOnSeat`, you can add a `mousemove` listener that tracks the mouse position and then checks if it's within the coordinates using the same calculation to know where to draw the seat.

Answer (score -1):

If your seating plan is just full of squares, why not use divs with hover effects and onclick listeners.

Comment: Another question is not an answer.  If you have questions, you should resolve them first in comments before posting an answer.